# Create an object dynamically from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

Can I create an object dynamically from JSON?

This is one of some in array:

```
values: [{
        "$type": "Entrance, DataModel",
        "EntranceDeviceData": {
            "$type": "DeviceData, DataModel",
            "Watchdog": 0,
            "Inputs": {
                "$type": "Int16[], mscorlib",
                "$values": [0, 0]
            },
            "Outputs": {
                "$type": "Int16[], mscorlib",
                "$values": [0, 0]
            },
            "Faults": {
                "$type": "Int16[], mscorlib",
                "$values": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            },
            "StandingCommand": 0
        },
        "Vehicle": null,
        "NextStates": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
            "$values": ["CarApproachingBarrier"]
        },
        "Repository": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib"
        },
        "Direction": 0,
        "Name": "Entrance",
        "Position": "0,0,0,0",
    }, {...another object...
    }, {...another one...
    }
]
```

This both JSON objects are different. Can I create an object (for every other JSON object) without knowing in advance it's properties? How can I do it?

(I heard something that it possible, but maybe I didn't understand well the person who said that).

Comment: What do you mean by *Can I create a object (for every other JSON object)*?

Comment: What you have there is _not_ JSON. JSON is always a string representation that happens to look similar to that. What you have there are simply two objects created via object literals.

Comment: I'll try to explain what I meant (I edited the code to be part of my real object): I need to create some array objects from its data. Every array related to different "$type" of objects ("Entrance, DataModel", "Spot, DataModel", "Exit, DataModel" and some more. I need to create those arrays without knowing all kind of "$type" I have I my JSON object.

Comment: the code you give is not syntactically correct: there are backticks and number that don't belong in javascript:  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib]

Answer (score 0):

What you gave as examples of JSON in your original code above is Javascript's way of defining literal objects. json1 and json2 already ARE javascript objects, no need to create them.

```
// original code from question
var json1 = {
   "mysex": "female",
   "yoursex": "male",
   "location": {
       "lat": "48",
       "lng": "1"
   },
   "description": "descr2",
   "owner": "zBYnfuu8DXEwMttwZ",
   "nickname": "user",
   "_id": "1"
};
```

As nnnnnn pointed out below JSON is most commonly used to refer to a STRING containing code formatted as above, that would be:

```
var json1_as_string = '{
   "mysex": "female",
   "yoursex": "male",
   "location": {
       "lat": "48",
       "lng": "1"
   },
   "description": "descr2",
   "owner": "zBYnfuu8DXEwMttwZ",
   "nickname": "user",
   "_id": "1"
}';
```

To get from such a String to an actual Javascript Object you would need to parse it:

```
var json1 = JSON.parse(json1_as_string);
```

the opposite direction (Javascript Object to  String) is achieved by stringify:

```
var json1_as_string = JSON.stringify(json1);
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON

p.s.

It does seem strange that these two very different objects have the same "_id".

Comment: The term "JSON" isn't supposed to be used to describe object literals in JavaScript code, it describes a string format used for data transfer which is based on JavaScript's object literal syntax but is a subset thereof. (Unfortunately the guy who came up with the term "JSON" didn't really think through the confusion he was going to cause.)

Comment: First, you right about id's: I changed it. I copied it from other post and duplicate it. Second: this is not what I meant. I explained myself better in the comments above

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the question completely, and I'm trying to understand what you are asking.

> This both JSON objects are different. Can I create an object (for
>   every other JSON object) without knowing in advance it's properties?
>   How can I do it?

Yes, in Javascript you can create objects without knowing their properties in advance. Javascript is not strongly typed, and it has no classes.  So there's absolutely no problem
with having objects with different properties.